# Latch IC for TFT application

Tags: latch

This looks little odd to ask here, but I have stuck in situation where I have my hardware ready and unfortunately the footprint used is of some other part no. Due to time constraint, I cant rework with PCB development and I don't want to add floating connections anywhere in hardware.

To be more specific, I have used SN74HCT245, 3 state buffer with 3rd state as isolation. It's pinning diagram is as shows:

[image: SN74HCT245 Pinning Diagram]

But, I need Latch IC (3rd state as latch, instead isolation) for my application. Is there any part no. with same pinning diagram and matching footprint as shown in the image above to fulfill my requirement.

Thank you.

Comment: I assume you're saying you need a latch rather than a bidirectional buffer. Does it need to be bidirectional, too? And if not, which side needs to be input?

Comment: It's bidirectional latch with same pin diagram shown above.

Comment: I had a quick flick through Wikipedia's list of 7400 series ICs, and I'm pretty sure no such part exists. In fact, there are no bidirectional latches at all.

Comment: Sorry, it's unidirectional latch.

Comment: Okay, so which side needs to be input?

Comment: A side ( left as per image )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution with a pinout close to the '245 would be to use a PAL16R8 programmed to provide the latching function you need. Unfortunately, its output enable is on pin 11 rather than pin 19, so you'd still need a couple of wires.